# Why is $\mathbb{R}^2$ not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vectors

> I cannot understand why $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

My reasoning is as follows:
Choose any elements $v_1$ and $v_2$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$, add them together you get an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and same for scalar multiplication and $0$ vector is an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, for exactly the reasons you give.

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb {R}^2$ are ordered pairs, the elements of $\mathbb {R}^3$ are ordered triples. An ordered pair is not an ordered triple.

Comment: is it that they are not of the same form?

Comment: You have a straightforward *embedding* $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$, $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)$. But *allows a straightforward embedding* is not the same as *is a subset*. Especially, nothing prevents your neighbour from considering $(x,y)\mapsto (0,x,y)$ straightforwrd.

Comment: $R^2$ and $R^3$ are different objects completely. One of these sets consists of formal ordered $pairs$, whereas the other one consists of formal ordered $triples$. Since pairs and triples are different things as formal objects, one cannot be contained in the other. It's really just this technical point.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is NOT a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but isomorphic to any $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^2\simeq \mathbb{R}^2\times0 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Is the idea the same if we change the dimensions to say $\mathbb{R}^4$ & $\mathbb{R}^5$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  this question is too old and which can be made as duplicate of the new one. May be I am wrong. But I still believe it's possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The space $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to the subset $(a,b,0)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3,$ but it's also isomorphic to infinitely many other 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3.$ Therefore, there's no canonical embedding, and you don't usually think of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as being contained in $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Another explanation is the vector (a,b) is not the same as the vector (a,b,0). We have a vector with 2 components & a vector with 3 components, so they are different objects.

Before you can discuss whether $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ you need to embed $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by defining an isomorphism between a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ & all of $\mathbb{R}^2.$ An obvious one is

\begin{equation*}
(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\leftrightarrow (a,b,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3.
\end{equation*}

As I mentioned above there are infinite ways to do it. For example, another isomorphism to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is

\begin{equation*}
(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\leftrightarrow (a,0,b)\in\mathbb{R}^3
\end{equation*}

In order to discuss whether elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are closed under addition in $\mathbb{R}^3,$ you first need to know how you map an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the isomorphism). If you've done that, you should be able to show (using the subspace criteria), that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3.$

However you cannot say $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3.$

What if you choose to embed $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by

\begin{equation*}
(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2\leftrightarrow (a,b,1)\in\mathbb{R}^3?
\end{equation*}

Clearly the zero vector is not in the embedded $\mathbb{R}^2,$ so it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Does that help?

Comment: yes very clear indeed. thnk you